# Array to Dictionary in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I have an array that outputs in NSLog:

```
log: (
        {
        "case_color" = White;
        "case_description" = "";
        "case_image" = "http://site.com/get/parts/part_images/nzxtphantom410.jpeg";
        "case_name" = "NZXT Phantom 410";
        "case_price" = "99.99";
        "case_type" = ATX;
        id = 1;
    }
)
```

How can I put this in a NSDictionary so I can call it like:

```
NSDictionary *object;
NSString *casename object[@"case_name"];
```

and casename is equal to "NZXT Phantom 410"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your array has a single element which is a dictionary.  Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *caseName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"case_name"];
```